# Basic authentication with Extjs store

Tags: javascript, extjs, jsonp, basic-authentication, sencha-architect

I have the following store in ExtJS.I need to send an authentication header with this request for basic authentication. Is it possible to do with this?

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.DataGridModels', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'store.datagridmodels',

    requires: [
        'MyApp.model.DataGridModel',
        'Ext.data.proxy.JsonP'
    ],

    constructor: function(cfg) {
        var me = this;
        cfg = cfg || {};
        me.callParent([Ext.apply({
            storeId: 'DataGridModels',
            autoLoad: true,
            model: 'MyApp.model.DataGridModel',
            proxy: {
                type: 'jsonp',
                url: 'http://example.com/data.php'
            }
        }, cfg)]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my application `init` function I do this:

```
Ext.Ajax.on('beforerequest', function (conn , options , eOpts) {

    // Get a token from the internal storage.
    // We have gotten it during the authentication procedure.
    var token = window.localStorage.authToken;
    if (!token) return;

    options.headers = options.headers ? {};
    options.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token);
    // Usually I use lodash code:
    // _.set(options, ['headers', 'Authorization'], 'Bearer ' + token)
});
```

It will modify every Ajax request appending the authorization header.

If the "Basic" authentication scheme is used, the value for the Authorization header is constructed like this:

1. The username and the password are combined with a colon (username:password).
2. The resulting string is base64 encoded (dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=).

So, if the base64 string was calculated before and saved in window.localStorage.baseAuthenticationToken the code will be like that:

```
Ext.Ajax.on('beforerequest', function (conn , options , eOpts) {
    var token = window.localStorage.baseAuthenticationToken;
    if (!token) return;
    options.headers = options.headers ? {};
    options.headers.Authorization = 'Basic ' + token);
});
```